# Displaying office documents in web browser without allowing it to get downloaded

Tags: html

i want to display word documents in my web browser without allowing it to get downloaded i tried with Iframe but it displays only pdf files but not office documents need help to solve this issue..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you don't want people to have it, don't put it on the Internet.

Comment: @JohnConde no not like that in my case i want to display the documents based on user permissions thats why i am working for it......

Answer (score 1):

You have to render office document into html. If your document is office open xml. than you can extract it and read the xml data file inside then render them.

The easiest way is using `Google Docs` to open document on your site

FYI. Opening pdf on iframe is actually download it and let adds-on on the browser to display it. So, user can still download your pdf.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i don't know how to make google docs to display a locally stored office document in my hard drive

Comment: @Karthik. Is your web site online into the internet?

Comment: no i am making a demo version so i have to achieve this task by displaying local documents .

Comment: So, you have to render office document. Or like pdf, you create adds-on for your browser to display document. Or you can use Silverlight from microsoft.